# How many (if any) survivors of the Yavin Death Star were there?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, death-star

How many (if any) survivors were there from the Battle of Yavin Death Star explosion? It seems there should have been escape pods and/or other means of escape from such a massive military vehicle. According to canon, how many survived, and, generally, how did they manage it?

Comment: Did you see the explosion? It went nova, there would have been no chance of survival for anyone onboard.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack there was one, but he wasn't on board at the time (although was technically a survivor of the Yavin Deathstar)

Comment: @TheDoc that's why I said "onboard". We don't know how many Death Star personnel were off site at the time of the explosion

Comment: Do you count those who evacuated just before the explosion, or just those that were in it while it exploded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1 survived

According to the [Wookieepedia page on the Battle of Yavin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Yavin/Canon), which cites the **canon** book [Lost Stars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lost_Stars), there was only one survivor: Darth Vader.  Well, you could say two survivors, as Darth Vader's TIE fighter also survived, but that's not a person.  So, how did he manage it I hear you ask (well, I didn't hear you ask, I just saw that you asked that) - well, he wasn't on board the Death Star at the time (go to 40 seconds in the below video):

So, that makes nearly two million people casualties in the Battle of Yavin on the Death Star *alone*!

Comment: This makes sense but what about the TIE Fighters?  True, they aren't equipped with hyperdrives, butYavin wasn't far away.  A TIE Fighter pilot could have easily flown to the moon base, landed and lived in the wild.

Answer (score 4):

In the first of the Young Jedi Knights books (Heirs to the Force), the major plot thread is about a TIE fighter pilot named Qorl from the Battle of Yavin that crashed on Yavin 4 and has been surviving in the jungle nearby Luke's new Jedi Academy for the intermediate 23 years, so thoroughly indoctrinated that he's sure the Empire must still be around.

Source: [Wookieepedia entry for "Heirs of the Force"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Young_Jedi_Knights:_Heirs_of_the_Force)

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding sources and elaborating a little. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cassio Tagge left the Death Star before its destruction.

[image: General Cassio Tagge]

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding sources and elaborating a little. :)